# T-SQL Move XML node without insert/delete

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xpath, xquery

Using T-SQL, is it possible to move an XML node with a single instruction, rather than having to do an `insert` followed by a `delete`?

Example XML...

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '<data><a></a><b></b></data>'
```

Desired XML...

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '<data><a><b></b></a></data>'
```

Two step solution...

```
SET @XML.modify('insert (/data/b) as last into (/data/a)[1]')
SET @XML.modify('delete (/data/b)')
```

Is there a one step solution?

Comment: I'm confused, why not insert it the correct way first? By correct i mean the way you want it.

Comment: Sorry @scsimon, but is that a serious question?  I'm not building the "example" XML... I'm converting it.  If I was building it in the first place, do you think I'd specifically put it in the wrong location to then move it??

Comment: Your example is very simplified (that's good), but will your *real-life* XML be the same in structure (move one *level-2* element into one *level-1* element)? Or do you need a *fully-blown-generic-move-from-here-to-there-magic*?

Comment: @Shnugo - does it matter?  A single level-1 element will be moved to a single level-3 element, but AFAIK that shouldn't make any difference to the question/answer.  To be honest, my two step solution works... I was purely interested (for a tiny tiny performance gain, but mainly for personal knowledge) if there was a single `.modify` command that would do it

Comment: No, there is not... `.modify()` will allow one single change per call. Depending on the actual XML one can 1) shred and rebuild it, try some fancy `XQuery`, but this will not work generically.

Comment: @Shnugo - fair enough. Make it an answer and I will mark it accepted

Comment: @freefaller I constantly see folks asking a question and over simplify it only to get an easy answer like shnug posted and then say “well actually...” so yes, it was a serious attempt to get you to post real xml or explain the question more. It wasn’t needed in this case apparently.

Comment: @scsimon - understood.  I've been a developer for over 20 years, so I'm aware of gotchas like that.  I couldn't count the number of times I've started writing questions that have become **so** involved due to their complexity that I've given up for fear that it becomes a TL;DR :-)

Comment: Fair enough @freefaller

Comment: @freefaller About your *purely interested (for a tiny tiny performance gain, but mainly for personal knowledge)*: This is something I'd like to have too... Needing two statements often makes the difference between *ad-hoc* and *procedural* - which I try to avoid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you asked me to place my comment as answer:

No, there is not...

`.modify()` will allow one single change per call.

Depending on the actual XML one can

1. shred and rebuild it or
2. try some fancy `XQuery` (but TSQL's `XQuery` is very limited with constructed XML...)

Both will not work generically.